# On window resize get new width and last one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I`m trying build function who on document width changes get current webpage windows size and save last of past width with function, so i need past value.
So in pseido code  it will be:

```
on resize(function){
var CURENT_W = 100
**var PAST_W   = 90**
var MODIFIER = CURENT_W - PAST_W
jQuert('#element').css('atribute': MODIFIER)
});
```

**So i need  function who tell  me how much window is resized.**

How to get old document width? It`s possile?
Maybe there is some better method?

Comment: You can store the actual window's width inside a variable 'var documentWidth = $("body").width();' and then use conditionals to do "something" if window changes.
`if (documentWidth !== documentWidth) {bla bla bla} else {bla bla}`
Or maybe I didn't get your point. If not, I'm so sorry :)

Comment: @Frondor I need function who tell me how much window is resized.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't get what you're trying to explain. You should code something before somebody can help you on this website.
I don't know if you are talking about browser windows, o simple modals / html elements being resized.

Comment: why would you need this? Resize event fires many times a second while resizing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made a little snippet for you, you can use it as you want, just try to understand the script.
I'm 100% it can be done in some easier way, but this is the first that came to my mind

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        // store a variable with body's width
        var initial = $("body").width();
        // render the body's width value on the selector
        $("#initialwidth, #actualwidth").text(initial);

    //now let's resize
    $(window).resize(function() {        
        // Before doing some maths, let's get the width from #actualwidth span instead of directly from the variable
        // the span has the value "static" because it was defined outside the ".resize()" event
        var staticWidth = $("#initialwidth").text();
        var newWidth = $("body").width();
//new width - initial width = difference
        var finalWidth = newWidth - staticWidth + "px";
        $("#actualwidth").text(newWidth);
        $("#diff").text(finalWidth);
    });


});
```

Here's a jsfiddle:

### http://jsfiddle.net/2dcsonjg/